# SSIS: addrows stops after adding one row out of many

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm trying to process an xml file I'm getting from a vendor.  I managed to get some c# code to read in all 26 items in the xml.  This code I placed into a script component in SSIS and fed that into a Union All task.  I then placed a dataviewer so I can verify what I received.  I use this code to add the rows to the output buffer:

```
            Roles roles = GetWebServiceResult(wUrl);
        MessageBox.Show("We have read in " + roles.Items.Length + " items");

        //Add each role entry to the output buffer.
        for (int i = 0; i < roles.Items.Length; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Adding item " + (i + 1) + " to the output");
            Transfer role = getRole(roles.Items[i]);
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.roleKey = role.roleKey;
            Output0Buffer.text = role.text;
            Output0Buffer.Item = role.Item;
            Output0Buffer.Users = role.Users;
        }
```

When I run this I get a popup saying that there are 26 items to process, but I only get one more popup after that, telling me that item #1 has been added.  the job then stops with no errors, but I only have one row of output in the dataviewer.  I don't understand why this is happening when I know that there are 25 more items to add.

Additional: On a whim, I took out the Output0Buffer code and it went through all 26 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I ran it using Ctrl-F5 and studied the output in the console.  Turns out a column wasn't big enough.  I made that column larger and everything works.  I would have thought that error would have stopped the processing.

Comment: Well, that's strange you didn't get an error. Not even warning??

Comment: Nope and I even had a try...catch block around the whole thing.